# APIs & services disappeared from Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Not sure if there was some sort of update, but before I could access the "APIs & services" by following the official instructions [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en):

```
* If the APIs & services page isn't already open, open the console left side menu and select APIs & services.
* On the left, click Credentials.
```

When I open up the console and select the project there's no choice for APIs & services..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `Open the console left side menu` part is not referring to the menu that's already open on the left.. It's referring to the hamburger bun menu that you have to click also.. which opens up another menu on the left.

Hopefully this will help others..

[image]